# Reassign an existing case using active assignment rules

Tags: case, assignment-rules

In some situations I want to reassign an existing case to the default queue defined with the active assignment rules. However, I do not know how to reassign an existing case using assignment rules. I need to do this using a workflow rule or in Apex.

Does anyone have an idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I found.  There's a link to do this with apex programmatically, and you may need to call the assignmentRuleHeader class in an update trigger.

> From a standard UI, a user can trigger assignment rules by simply
>   checking the "Assign using active assignment rules" checkbox under the
>   Optional section. The problem arises when your app needs to insert the
>   Case from Apex and wants to trigger assignment rules. Using this
>   script, a Case will be inserted but assignment rules will not be
>   triggered as there is no such field "Assign using active assignment
>   rules" on Case.
>
> Code can be found here:
>   http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/running-case-assignment-rules-from-apex

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000187821&language=en_US

I've taken the liberty of writing a simplified trigger and class with a method (having @future annotation --> rationale found here: [Case Assignment Rule workaround](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19412/case-assignment-rule-workaround)).  This concept can be extended to a Trigger on the User object, which can call the Case Reassignment method after a User is deactivated.  Note, I intentionally did not bulkify the code to better demonstrate the concept.

In my coded example, I created a custom field [Reassign_with_Active_Assignment_Rule__c] (checkbox) to trigger the class to run and invoke the standard Case reassignment functionality.

```
trigger MyCaseReassignmentTrigger on Case (before update) {

    for(Case c : trigger.new){

        //only run trigger when my business condiions are met and not invoked by an @future method to avoid infinite recursion
        if(c.Reassign_with_Active_Assignment_Rule__c && !System.isFuture()){

            MyCaseReassignmentClass.reassignCaseWithActiveRule(c.Id);            

        }

    }

}




public class MyCaseReassignmentClass {


    /*
     * Pass the ID values to a future method, and perform your ownership changea synchronously.
     * This will allow you to reassign the user correctly after the assignment rule logic has executed.
     * Source: sfdcfox https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/40004/15114
     */

    @future
    public static void reassignCaseWithActiveRule(ID myCaseId) {

        //fetching the desired assignment rules on Case...
        AssignmentRule AR = new AssignmentRule();
        AR = [select id from AssignmentRule where SobjectType = 'Case' and Active = true limit 1];

        //recreating the DMLOptions setting for "Assign using active assignment rules" checkbox on Case object...
        Database.DMLOptions dmlOpts = new Database.DMLOptions();
        dmlOpts.assignmentRuleHeader.assignmentRuleId= AR.id;

        //get current instance of sObject (Case)...
        Case myCase = [select Id, Reassign_with_Active_Assignment_Rule__c from Case where Id =: myCaseId limit 1];

        //set DMLOptions on this record so it will be processed suing assignment rules...
        myCase.setOptions(dmlOpts);
        myCase.description = 'processed w/ @future on '+ dateTime.now();

        update myCase; 

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Jim, but this feature is related only to a newly created cases and I know how to deal with them. Unfortunately, I need to reassign an existing case when its owner becomes inactive for whatever reason.

Comment: @DmitryNikolaev, check my revised answer and let me know if this will work.  I tested this in my org and it would reassign the case each time the method was called.

Comment: I did not think that this should work when updating a case as well. Thank you James, this is what I need!

Comment: @james Would you be able to provide test classes for the code you provided above?