# Case Assignment Rules - Assign Case to Account Team Role

Tags: assignment-rules

I use Account Teams, and one of the roles is Case Manager. For a lot of accounts, the Case Manager is different, so creating a queue and put the case manager in there, is not feasible.

When I create a new case, I want to be able to automatically assign that case to the Case Manager. Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks, Lily.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible without writing APEX code. So you will have to create a trigger on Case that looks up the Case Manager and does the assignment.

There are some peculiarities that you need to take into account, as discussed here:
[Case Assignment Rule workaround](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19412/case-assignment-rule-workaround)